# How to learn the stroke order of a kanji (or kana) character using Emacs

Tags: minor-mode, learning

As a devoted Emacs user and a Japanese beginner learner, I've been using the Emacs' Japanese input method quite a lot during recent months. However, I've been looking for a way to leverage Emacs' multilingual capabilities to augment the process of learning kanji signs with their rigid order of strokes.

Comment: I don't know if the following can help. By `M-x set-input-method` you can select `japanese, japanese-ascii, japanese-hankaku-kana, japanese-hiragana, japanese-katakana, japanese-zenkaku`. Then the rules of transliteration can be used to type Japanese characters. This uses quail.

Comment: Hey, @Name. What you're writing about is surely helpful when writing in Japanese, since transliteration is the basis for input when you have 2500+ common signs. But the problem that I'm addressing in the answer is quite a different one. Namely, you can take a Japanese text with various kanji signs (or even input them using the above input methods) and then point cursor to them and retrieve the stroke order in an SVG form. Please, visit the Github website to see the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

I spent some time writing an Emacs mode to help discover the stroke order of a kanji sign under the cursor ('at point' in the Emacs jargon). I'd like to share a link to my project with all Emacs users and Emacs user wannabes. It's available [here](https://github.com/wsgac/kanji-mode) on Github. It makes strong use of the [KanjiVG](http://kanjivg.tagaini.net/) project, whose authors have catalogued various (all?) characters and provided SVG diagrams for their respective stroke orders. I hope someone will find this mode useful on their adventure with the Japanese language.

EDIT:
To make its use more convenient I submitted the package to [MELPA](http://melpa.org/). It is now officially available via `package`. The package's MELPA site can be viewed [here](http://melpa.org/#/kanji-mode).
Hope this will help people try out this mode.